# Always Homepage is shared when using facebook page sharing plugin

Tags: facebook, wordpress

in one of my website when I share any page or post using facebook/twitter share plugin, it is always show my homepage. like: http://shemiafagan.com/about-shemia/ if you share this page, this exact page ll not popped up, instead the home page gets shared everytime. I've tried different plugin, but the result is same. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `og:url` on the page http://shemiafagan.com/about-shemia/ is set to the homepage, as visible in the source code:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://shemiafagan.com"/>
```

It needs to be

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://shemiafagan.com/about-shemia/"/>
```